# Split string in Lua and print selected keys

Tags: string, split, lua

I'm looking for a little help with splitting a string using Lua and printing selected parts of it.  I have this code so far:

```
b = "an example string"

for i in string.gmatch(b, "%w+") do
   print(i)
end
```

Output is...

```
  an
  example
  string
```

How do I go about printing only bits of the result?

I've tried the following but just returns a list of "nils":

```
b = "an example string"

for i in string.gmatch(b, "%w+") do
   print(i[1])
end
```

So if I wanted to print:

```
string
example
```

How would this work? I was pretty sure I just added the value assigned to the key that is in memory, like [0] or [1].  But I must be wrong..

In this use case the sample text will remain the same, only time stamps will change in the string.  I just need to reorder the words.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Do you want to collect all the words in an array?

Comment: Sure, however is best to be able to call them out individually or combined would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I can find is to use the loop to store the matches in an array. Then you can access them with literal indexes:

```
b = "an example string"

local words = {}
for i in string.gmatch(b, "%w+") do
  table.insert(words, i)
end

print(words[3])
print(words[2])
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it and feedback.  Appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing (probably perferable) answer, you could also do some manual work with a counter:

```
counter = 0
for i in string.gmatch(b, "%w+") do
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter > 1 then print(i) end
end
```

Or, here's a one-liner (that wouldn't scale with larger strings though and also doesn't insert a newline between second and third word):

```
print(string.match(b, "%w+%s+(%w+)%s+(%w+)"))
```

Comment: Thank you.  Apologies, I should have stated that in my use case for this, the example text will be pretty much the same every time.  So this doesn't need to cater for different sized strings.  I'll update the main case details above.